# Angular ui-router scroll to top, not to ui-view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

I've just upgraded to `ui-router 0.2.8` from `0.2.0` and I've noticed that when the state changes, the scroll position jumps to the top of te child `ui-view` that is the subject of the new state.

This is fine but I have two problems with it:

1) I have 30px padding between the top of the page and the `ui-view` and I would like it to scroll to the top of the page, leaving a gap. At the moment it goes exactly to the top of the `ui-view` which looks ugly. To achieve this I guess I either need to know how to get it to scroll to the top of the div that the ui-view is in (not the browser `viewport`), or I need to find out how to override `$uiViewScroll` to scroll to the `ui-view` minus 30px.

I have tried `$uiViewScrollProvider.useAnchorScroll();` but if I do that it doesn't scroll at all. I have also tried `<ui-view autoscroll="false">;`, which also stops the scrolling completely.

2) It doesn't actually scroll at the moment, just jumps. Is it suppose to scroll or is it up to the developer to do this with CSS transitions?

Any help would really be appreciated :)

Comment: can you provide a live demo?

Comment: Very difficult without getting my whole app into plunker. I will try but not sure how I'm going to simplify it.

Comment: well, simplifying it may be the first step towards the solution. it will help you grasp things clearer.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Another approach is to decorate the default `$uiViewScroll` service, effectively overriding the default behaviour.

```
app.config(function ($provide) {
  $provide.decorator('$uiViewScroll', function ($delegate) {
    return function (uiViewElement) {
      // var top = uiViewElement.getBoundingClientRect().top;
      // window.scrollTo(0, (top - 30));
      // Or some other custom behaviour...
    }; 
  });
});
```

And as Hubrus mentioned, for any `<ui-view>` you do not wish this to apply for, simply add `autoscroll="false"`. I haven't taken a good look into the actual scrolling implementation, I just figured I'd mention the decorator way (it's alot of fun) as an alternative. I'm sure you can work out the exact scrolling behaviour.

Comment: Thanks, now that I have access to the uiViewElement I guess I could access attributes to see if i've added (for example) elementToScrollTo="main-body" etc ?

Comment: I would assume so, it's not something I've attempted myself but it sounds feasible. I've only ever used this to null-ify the default scrolling behaviour as it just doesn't fly well with me :) Do let me know if it works out, would be interesting to know of any 'kinks' with this approach. Good luck!

Comment: @jonhobbs were either of you able to get this solution working? I attempted it yet it did not solve the problem

Comment: I tried but it was complicated. Not very neat but in the end I just put this in the view's controller --- /* Scroll to top of page */
 $scope.$watchCollection('stateParams', function(){
  $(".mainLayout-body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 300);
 });

Comment: @jonhobbs If you're OK with each state going to the top of the page, I'd recommend using $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function() { $window.scollTo(0,0) }); rather than performing a watch collection on the $stateParams.

Comment: the `uiViewElement` is returned as an array.  I was able to get this working by: `var top = uiViewElement[0].getBoundingClientRect().top;`

Comment: Note that you cannot scroll to a position other than 0 if there is no scroll bar. You should therefore wrap the call to `scrollTo()` in a `$timeout`. This is also how it is done in the original implementation.

Answer (score 42):

when ever the path changes the router broadcasts an event: $stateChangeSuccess i.e. the url has changed so just listen to it and use jquery to scroll to the top of the page

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess',function(){
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 200);
})
```

place the above code inside

```
yourAppName.run(function(){

    //the above code here
 })
```

Comment: That sounds like like a good suggestion, although it's a scrollable div that I need to go to the top of, not the BODY tag, I'm sure I can work that out. Is it possible to make it so that I could override that for certain views though, so that I can elect not to scroll to the top (for example on a tabset half way down the page).

Comment: I found the answer, I used your jquery code but instead of putting it in $stateChangeSucess I put it in the controller for individual views. That way I can decide which views to include it in.

Comment: yes, putting that in controllers is also an option glad that works!

Comment: Using jquery?? Should really be possible without resorting to jQuery

Comment: using jquery is safe in this case thats what i feel because ui view will be inside the body tag and 100% of the times boy tag will be present in the dom its just the templates which will keep on changing inside the body tag. So i felt safe to use it! :)

Comment: A couple of answers work but this is the most elegant and correct imo, thank you

Comment: @Spock If you're OK without the animation you can just use `window.scrollTo(0, 0)`.

Answer (score 12):

So I had this same problem. I have a fixed-top nav bar. If I put autoscroll="true" in the ui-view it would scroll to the top minus the height of the height of the scroll bar.

So I got rid of the style that added the padding to the body for the top navbar

```
// fixed navigation at top
//body { padding-top: 100px; }
```

And applied it to the ui-view

```
[ui-view=main] {
    padding-top: 100px;
}
```

Now autoscroll="true" works as expected.

Answer (score 7):

1) I think the easiest way it to put `autoscroll="false"` on the ui-view and manipulate the scrolling in the `$viewContentLoaded` event.

2) This is the browser's default behavior on anchors

Comment: I can probably write the scrolling code, but not sure where in my code to hook in to the $viewContentLoaded (which I didn't actually know existed)

Answer (score 5):

Since `$stateChangeSuccess` seems not to be available anymore in current AngularJS (as 1.2.x) I changed
Rishul Mattas example to the following which works fine for me:

```
app.run(function ($rootScope) {
  $rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded',function(){
    jQuery('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 200);
  });
});
```

Comment: it has to be $rootScope!

Comment: I tried your solution and it almost gave me an headache until I found this little cause. Thanks for updating.

Answer (score 2):

Place on top

```
<div id="top">.....
```

Code to scroll:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function() {
    $anchorScroll('top');
});
```

Comment: Much cleaner to use angular native scrolling method. Nice!

Answer (score 1):

If one combines Angular + Material Design, this is also required to scroll to top:

```
app.run(function ($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function () {
        $("md-content").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "fast"); /* <------- Notice this line */
        jQuery('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 200);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that we don't need scrolling to top if navigating state is child state, so I wrote this:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess',function(_, _, _, os){
    if(!$state.includes(os) || $state.is(os))
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 200);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time it's not enough just to scroll to the top of the page. It is always a good idea to respect anchor links and to scroll to the specific place in the loaded content designated by location's hash.

Here's the code I use to implement this strategy:

```js
module.run(function (
  $rootScope,
  $timeout,
  $location,
  $uiViewScroll
) {

  // Scrolling when screen changed.
  $rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function () {
    $timeout(performAutoScroll, 0);
  });


  function performAutoScroll () {
    var hash = $location.hash();
    var element =
         findDomElement('#' + hash)
      || findDomElement('a[name="' + hash + '"]')
      || angular.element(window.document.body)
    ;
    $uiViewScroll(element);
  }
});
```

`$viewContentLoaded` is an event generated by Angular when content is loaded inside of the `ui-view` element. Actually, we need to postpone the execution of our code in order to move it to a next digest cycle. That way the content of the view element will be actually placed in the DOM tree, so we can query it. `$timeout` with zero delay trick is used for this purpose.

`$uiViewScroll` service, provided by *UI Router* is used to actually do the scrolling. We can pass a jQuery/jqLite element to it and it will scroll to it's top border.

We are getting the currect hash from the `$location` service and using it to find the proper element inside of the DOM tree. It could be either a element with `id` attribute or a link with `name` attribute. In case we can't find an element to scroll to we falling back to a `body` element (i.e. will scroll to the top of the page).

And the `findDomElement` is just a syntactic sugar. It defined like this:

```js
/**
 * @param {string} selector
 * @returns {jQuery|null}
 */
function findDomElement (selector) {
  var result = $(selector);
  return (result.length > 0 ? result : null);
}
```

I hope this approach makes sense and will be useful to someone out there. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to do this with views conditionally, you could place this in the controller view like so:

```
.state('exampleState', {
    url: '/exampleURL',
    controller: 'ExampleCtrl as examplectrl',
    onEnter: function($rootScope) {
            $rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded',function(){
            jQuery('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 200);
        });
    }
}).
```

or optionally which might keep your state.js file cleaner place the above in the controller for given view:

```
function ExampleCtrl ($scope, $rootScope) {

    $rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded',function(){
            jQuery('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 200);
        });
}
```

Hope this helps someone, please let me know if I'm missing something. I used the latter and works great for me.