# Angular UI Router - How to use $uiViewScroll in code

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am new to AngularJS and Angular UI Router. I am wanting to decorate and call angular ui router's $uiViewScroll from javascript code but cannot figure out how to do so. Can someone please help me figure this out?

For the decoration part I have found: [Angular ui-router scroll to top, not to ui-view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22290570/angular-ui-router-scroll-to-top-not-to-ui-view)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @StenMuchow New to SO so didn't know we could do that. Thanks for making me aware!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a small example how you can get it to fire.

```
'use strict';

angular.module('Directives.ScrollTop', [])

    .directive('scrollTop', function($uiViewScroll) {

        var linker = function (scope, element, attr) {

            $uiViewScroll(element);

        };

        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: linker
        }

    });
```