# ui-scroll-to smooth scroll in angularjs

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I'm using **`ui-scroll-to`**

I need to scroll this smoothly. also it should stop before 100px in mentioned element.

```
<a ui-scroll-to="msg-container" >
   Go to Msg
</a>

<div id="msg-container">
   msgs
</div>
```

smooth scroll like `.scrollTop()` in jquery

Comment: u can just use jquery i don't think angular has something like that. I had the same problem and I've used  jQuery. Another alternative is to make your own directive with does the scroll with jquery so you can use it in different places

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work. You might have to tweak the target.offset().top a bit if you have a fixed header or something similar that might mess with the offset.

```
app.config(function ($provide) {
  $provide.decorator('$uiViewScroll', function ($delegate) {
    return function (uiViewElement) {
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: uiViewElement.offset().top
        }, 500);
    };
  });
});
```

Keep `autoscroll="true"` on your ui-view.

See other answer for credit on the prodiver: [Angular ui-router scroll to top, not to ui-view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22290570/angular-ui-router-scroll-to-top-not-to-ui-view).

Comment: in HTML how to I use? Also I have fixed header.